# SQL Query Quick Question

Tags: sql

The following does not work. I get the error message that it doesn't recognize Query.Field4, Query.Field5, and Query.Field6 :

```
SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
WHERE ((Table.Field1=Query.Field4)
  AND ((Table.Field2)=(Query.Field5))
  AND (Table.Field3=Query.Field6));
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
I have an issue though, I need to be able to edit the records and when I use the JOIN clause it will not let me edit the records.

Comment: there is nothing mentioned about `Table2` in ths query, how are you getting this error?

Comment: Where is table2 in your query? Did this get edited wrong?

Comment: oops, i meant query for table2. I'll edit that really quick. Thank you!

Comment: alright, that is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Which database is this? Do you mean you want to edit the records as you select them?

Comment: @lobster1234 This is in Access. And the records selected in this query will be displayed on a form and I want them to be editable in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't put a JOIN clause in your statement.

For example:

```
SELECT  Table.*
FROM    Table
JOIN    Query ON   (Table.Field1 = Query.Field4) AND
                   (Table.Field2 = Query.Field5) AND
                   (Table.Field3 = Query.Field6)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As you're using a GUI editor to edit rows in a table, you might need to do something like this:

```
SELECT  Table.*
FROM    Table
WHERE   Table.UniqueIdentifier IN (
            SELECT  Table.UniqueIdentifier
            FROM    Table
            JOIN Query ON (Table.Field1 = Query.Field4) AND
                          (Table.Field2 = Query.Field5) AND
                          (Table.Field3 = Query.Field6)
        )
```

The query above assumes that you have a primary key set on your table, or a column that gives each row it's own unique identifier (such as an incrementing integer, or a GUID).

Comment: @Karl Nicoll I have an issue though, I need to be able to edit the records and when I use the JOIN clause it will not let me edit the records.

Comment: @Zack - I'm assuming that you're using a GUI editor to edit rows by hand. I've added another query to my answer that should work for you, although I can't offer any guarantees.

Comment: Yes, this is in MS-Access which I think is a terrible db program but it's not my choice.  What is a primary key?

Comment: @Zack - A primary key is a column that is used to uniquely identify each row in your tables. It is usually an incrementing number (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc).

Comment: since you can not simply extend selections in access as you would excel how can I add an incrementing number on 1800 records?

Comment: @Zack - Take a look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/fields-that-generate-numbers-automatically-in-access-HA001055067.aspx . *NOTE: Make a copy of your database before making changes so that you can go back to the old version if you go wrong.*